# How should I use `systemctl --global`?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, sudo, systemctl

Systemd has a flag `--global`, on my distribution, Ubuntu, I'm finding a catch-22.

- If I run it as an unprivileged user, systemctl will not have the proper permissions to copy the unit file into `/etc`.
- It won't work via `sudo`, as `sudo` fails to set up the `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and the `$XDG_*` variables.

It may or may not work via `sudo -E`, which preserves the environment. It definitely works if running from a `root` session (e.g. from a virtual console).

What is the proper way to use `systemctl --global`?

Comment: What dbus error are you getting? Can you paste it here?

Comment: Also be interested in seeing the result of `systemctl list-units --type=service --user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`--global`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--global): When used with `enable` and `disable`, operate on the global user configuration directory, thus enabling or disabling a unit file globally for all future logins of all users.

The `systemctl --global` flag references `systemctl --user` services on a "global" level, and is mainly used to `enable`/`disable` user units for *all users* on the system.

In contrast to `systemctl --system` units, enabled `--global` units do not *start* until an individual user *logs in* and thus "wants" the user unit. (Note that `sudo`/`su` do not "log in" a user in this sense; see below for alternatives.)

If you look at the [systemd user unit search path](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#User%20Unit%20Search%20Path), you'll notice that it contains some "global" directories which are not writeable by non-`root` users. Units in these directories can either be managed by `sudo systemctl --global` (for all users) or `systemctl --user` (for an individual user).

```bash
ls -l /usr/lib/systemd/user

ls -l /etc/systemd/user
```

Using `sudo systemctl --global` is limited to managing the units as *files*, primarily enabling/disabling them. Manually enabling a user unit globally will symlink it under targets/wants directories in `/etc/systemd/user`; for individual users it's `~/.config/systemd/user`.

```bash
ls -l ~/.config/systemd/user
```

---

On a desktop system, there can be quite a few global user units available, possibly enabled by default during (package) installation. The list of units "in memory" also includes generated and transient units/"files", such as [devices](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.device.html) and [scopes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.scope.html). Use, for example, `--type service` to narrow it down.

```bash
systemctl --global list-unit-files
```

```bash
systemctl --global list-units

systemctl --global list-units --all
```

While the list of `--global` user unit files may look very similar to that of an individual `--user`, the latter includes (non-global) user-specific directories in the search path. See also [`user.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/system.conf.d.html), where [additional user directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698459) can be configured.

```bash
systemctl --user list-units
```

```bash
systemctl --user list-unit-files
```

For a "live" list of unit search directories, including custom `user.conf` additions for the current user, use [`systemctl show`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemctl.html#show%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6%7CJOB%E2%80%A6).

```bash
systemctl --user show --property 'UnitPath' --value
```

(Just noted that while `systemctl --global list-unit-files` excludes those in `~/.config/systemd/user`, `systemctl --global list-units` includes them. Seems incorrect, or at least inconsistent?)

---

As user units do not load/execute until a user logs in, they have no `--global status`. You can instead look at the unit status for each individual logged in user, both yourself and others.

Since `sudo`/`su` doesn't actually perform a "proper log in" from systemd's view, it shouldn't be used to manage units of other users. Instead, have a look at [`--machine`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-M), where `@` and `.host` can be used to refer to the current system: `sudo systemctl --user --machine otheruser@.host`.

```bash
# NOTE: demo status for yourself, but via sudo.
sudo systemctl --user --machine "${USER}@.host" status
```

To instead "log in" as another user, as a separate session with all the DBus etcetera facilities in place, use [`machinectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machinectl.html) to start a `shell`. (Note that `machinectl login` will also start a shell, but as a more cumbersome "manual" login process.)

```bash
# NOTE: demo logging in as yourself, but with a custom/different login shell.
sudo machinectl shell "${USER}@.host" /bin/sh
```

See also [`loginctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html), and in particular `enable-linger` which allows long-running `--user` services without having to log in "manually".