# custom location for systemd services

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, d-bus

Is there a way to tell **systemd** to search in some path for services files ?

As this [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/systemd.unit.5.html) state, the search paths are determined during compile time. So I tried to set `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable in `/etc/systemd/user.conf`

```
Environment="XDG_DATA_DIRS=/custom/path/lib"
```

But It does not work.

PS: My service is activated through **DBus**.

Comment: What doesn't work? You've given no indication of what you did that didn't function in the way that you want other than editing a file.

Comment: systemd does not find my service in the custom location. I don't want to put it in /lib/share/systemd or /etc/systemd locations. 
systemd manpage says that it will look for units in many places including **$XDG_DATA_DIRS/systemd/user**  but when I set this env variables as said above it does not work

Comment: Are you using the `--system` bus (usual invocation of systemd) or are you using the `--user` bus?  If you are running `sudo systemctl {start,stop} foo.service`, you are running the system bus.  If you are running `systemctl --user {start,stop} foo.service` you are running the user bus.  `XDG_DATA_DIRS` only affects the user bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The --system bus

The systemd `--system` bus is the "normal" way to use systemd.  It's the system-wide bus and is run as `root`. `man systemd.unit` describes load paths for the `--system` bus as:

```
/etc/systemd/system.control
/run/systemd/system.control
/run/systemd/transient
/run/systemd/generator.early
/etc/systemd/system          <-- local units usually go here
/run/systemd/system
/run/systemd/generator
/usr/local/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system          <-- packaged units usually go here
/run/systemd/generator.late
```

This man page also says:

> When the variable `$SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` is set, the contents of this variable overrides the unit load path. If `$SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` ends with an empty component (":"), the usual unit load path will be appended to the contents of the variable

Setting this variable to `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/my/path/:` would add `/my/path` to the front of the load paths.  However, we cannot simply run this from the command line as systemd would already be running

```
SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/my/path: systemd
```

To set the environment of the `systemd` `--system` bus, we need to look at `man systemd-system.conf`.  Then set values in these files to affect the system bus:

```
/etc/systemd/system.conf
/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf   <-- Install your change here
/run/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf
/lib/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf
```

In terms of what to put in this configuration, the man page descirbes:

```
ManagerEnvironment=
    Takes the same arguments as DefaultEnvironment=, see above. Sets 
    environment variables just for the manager process itself. In contrast 
    to user managers, these variables are not inherited by processes spawned 
    by the system manager, use DefaultEnvironment= for that. Note that these
    variables are merged into the existing environment block. In particular, 
    in case of the system manager, this includes variables set by the kernel 
    based on the kernel command line.
```

Therefore install this file as `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/mypath.conf`:

```
[Manager]
ManagerEnvironment="SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH=/my/path:"
```

Disclaimer:  While `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` is documented in `man systemd.unit` of version 250.4 on my machine, it is not documented [here](https://systemd.io/ENVIRONMENT/).  That may mean that they are deprecating the feature.  If `SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH` is not described in the man page of your machine, then it is not yet (or no longer) supported.  In that case, the only option is to create symbolic links in `/etc/systemd/system/` to each of your units in whatever location they exist.

#### The --user bus

The systemd `--user` bus is something that runs for each user who is logged in.  It's useful for user-backups, user mounts, launching GUIs, or other desktop-environment stuff like VNC servers. To manage units on this bus, you run `systemctl --user {start,stop} ...` (without `sudo`).  `man systemd.unit` describes load paths for the `--user` bus as:

```
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/.config/systemd/user.control
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/user.control
/run/systemd/transient
/run/systemd/generator.early
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/.config/systemd/user or $HOME/.config/systemd/user
$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/.config/systemd/user or /etc/xdg/systemd/user
/etc/systemd/user
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/user
/run/systemd/user
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/generator
$XDG_DATA_HOME/systemd/user or $HOME/.local/share/systemd/user
$XDG_DATA_DIRS/systemd/user or /usr/local/share/systemd/user
$dir/systemd/user for each $dir in $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/local/lib/systemd/user/*
/usr/lib/systemd/user/*
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/generator.late/*
```

To set the environment of the systemd `--user` bus, we need to look at `man systemd-user.conf`. This setting values in these files to affect the `user` bus:

```
~/.config/systemd/user.conf     <-- Here if it should affect one user
/etc/systemd/user.conf
/etc/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf <-- Here if it should affect all user buses
/run/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf
```

In this case, I'm not sure if we should set `DefaultEnvironment=` or `ManagerEnvironment=`, so I would set both.

```
[Manager]
ManagerEnvironment="XDG_DATA_DIRS=/my/path:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/"
DefaultEnvironment="XDG_DATA_DIRS=/my/path:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/"
```

Then you need to put your units in `/my/path/systemd/user/`

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. This is what I just did and it works. The ManagerEnvironment is what i was looking for. The DefaultEnvironment is for process launched by systemd not systemd itself.

Comment: [Support for `%h` (equivalent to `$HOME`), `%u` (equivalent to `$USER`) and other user-specific "%"-specifiers in `user.conf`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/26675) allows for generic per-user `XDG_DATA_DIRS` path configuration. Am using this to have a shared location (git repository) with per-user services/timers/overrides, instead of "manually" adding/editing files in each users' `~/.config/systemd/user`. (Pull request has been merged in systemd, but has not yet been released at the time of writing.)

Comment: It would be nice to know how to get list of current load paths

Comment: @EugenKonkov: show user-level unit search paths (as currently configured in the runtime, in search order, empty directories omitted) with [systemctl show](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemctl.html#show%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6%7CJOB%E2%80%A6): `systemctl --user show --property 'UnitPath' --value` (or use `--system`).

Comment: @EugenKonkov: you can compare to static compile-time values in [systemd-analyze unit-paths](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-analyze.html#systemd-analyze%20unit-paths): `systemd-analyze --user unit-paths` and [system-path systemd-search-user-unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-path.html): `systemd-path systemd-search-user-unit`. There are also system-level and [user global-level](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749160) arguments for these commands.

Answer (score -1):

I belive you have to set the `$XDG_DATA_DIR` not has a bashrc/profile.d environment variable but as a systemd environment variable.

I belive the first example of [systemd.environment-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.environment-generator.html#) does what you want. I copied it below for quick reference:

```bsh
# 50-xdg-data-dirs.sh

#!/bin/sh
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0

# set the default value
XDG_DATA_DIRS="${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share/:/usr/share}"

# add a directory if it exists
if [ -d /opt/foo/share ]; then
    XDG_DATA_DIRS="/opt/foo/share:${XDG_DATA_DIRS}"
fi

# write our output
echo "XDG_DATA_DIRS=${XDG_DATA_DIRS}"
```

Another possibility is to define the systemd variables in `.conf` files in either `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/` or on a per service file as described in [this other SO](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this is not working either. I am still having the error :
dbus-daemon: Activation via systemd failed for unit MyService.service: unit MyService.service not found.
MyService.service  is located in $XDG_DATA_DIRS/systemd/user/.

Comment: Just to be more clear, the environment variable value is intented to be used by systemd itself not the service I am activating.

Comment: Yes. I know that it is a variable to be used by systemd itself.  @Stewart answer is actually also pointing (in much more detail and clarity than mine) that you need to instanciate them in .conf maybe the trick is `ManagerEnviornment` type.

Comment: yes this  was what i looking for. Thank you again.