# Custom systemd unit directory

Tags: systemd

Can systemd unit search paths be extended beyond the normal two system paths with systemd 219 (RHEL7)?

```
/etc/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system
```

Comment: For custom systemd unit directories check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698459/414186). For more information about default systemd paths (others than `/etc/systemd/system` and  `/lib/systemd/system`) run `man systemd.unit`

Comment: So much searching before asking here and now I wonder how I managed to miss it.  Thanks and I can’t wait to give it a try!

Comment: A pleasure! There are several useful `systemd` related answers on this site, so if you have any doubt you can search here or if you do not find anything useful you can ask the question. Also if that did not work for you let me know or leave a comment to Stewart's answer which is very useful.

Comment: If you could post this, I would be happy to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it would be better if you *upvote* the original answer (since this should be a duplicate). Regarding the *upvote* you will need  15 reputation to can do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom location for systemd services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698278/custom-location-for-systemd-services)

Comment: I think it would, if I were not stuck with RHEL 7.  I've been trying every possible combination of suggestions to get SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH to be recognized, without success.  RHEL7 uses systemd v219, which doesn't support ManagerEnvironment setting and for some reason, it doesn't manage to see the SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH when passed via the kernel command line.  /proc/1/environ is always empty (No strings) and the systemd unit path is always default.  Very frustrating (I don't have the reputation points yet to comment on that other thread).

Comment: @xl600 please [edit] your question to include that information, it will make it more obvious that this isn’t a duplicate.