# Put user's unit file in non-default location

Tags: systemd, rhel

My distro is RHEL 8.6. By default, all user's unit files are put in the `/home/myuser/.config/systemd/user` directory, then `systemctl --user daemon-reload` make them available. My question is how I change the directory to another one, says `/opt/home/myuser/.config/systemd/user`.

I found this: [Where do I put my systemd unit file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224992/where-do-i-put-my-systemd-unit-file) and this: [custom location for systemd services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698278/custom-location-for-systemd-services), but whatever variables I set, XDG_CONFIG_HOME, XDG_DATA_DIRS.... nothing works. `systemctl` still doesn't try to load unit file from my custom path.

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Symlink that to wherever your actual home directory is. Where is your home directory?

Comment: Because of [this issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RHEL-5899), all files including symbolic links under the user's home which is on NFS have to be avoided. And by the way, the [workaround Redhat gave](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6827941) is not working at all, the modification screw systemd-logind to 100% CPU.

Comment: I can't see the workaround (no subscription), but I think the suggestions in the bug report should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, there might be another bug, adding `RequiresMountsFor=/home/myuser` into `/etc/systemd/system/user@.service.d/home.conf`, the system is screwed, systemd-logind jumped to 100% CPU, anything related to systemd stopped working.

Comment: Hmm, what if you set the XDG variables in `user@.service` (assuming that manages the user session, I'll have to check)?

Comment: OK, thanks @muru, will try later.